# PHP why doesn´t the foreach function work?

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, foreach

Posting this again, because I am new and didn´t know how the questions should be formatted correctly.

Onto the question, I am supposed to do [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8nw7.png), as in this shoud be written out in a window, not in the code.

This is the full code (the variables were for a different excercise essentialy):

```
 $all_pics = glob("pics/*.*");
      $all_pics_clear = str_replace(["pics/",".jpg",".png"],"",$all_pics);
      $all_pics_clear = str_replace(["_","-"], " ",$all_pics_clear);
    
   

     for($i = 0; $i < count($all_pics); $i++){
        echo "{ type: 'quiz', title: '"
                .$all_pics_clear[$i]
                ."', pic: '"
                .str_replace("pics-new/","",$all_pics[$i])
                ."' },<br>";
    }
```

**Why doesn't the foreach function work with this?**

```
foreach ($all_pics as $filename) {
        echo "{ type: 'quiz', title: '"
            .$all_pics_clear
            ."', pic: '"
            .str_replace("pics-new/","",$all_pics)
            ."' },<br>";
    }
```

It kept telling me "array to string conversion error".

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\laragon\www\ukol8\ukolD\ukolD.php on line 38 { type: 'quiz', title: 'Array', pic: 'Array' },
```

**And why the for function does work with this?**

And because I am a beginner, I would appreciate an idiot-proof explanation, a lot of the programming concepts are just beyond me, I even had to look up the for function solution, because that would literally never occur to me to do.

**edit**: updated the code with the for loop, as that one works, the fact that glob returns arrays was helpful..i dont know the proper way around php programming and stackoverflow, so it might take me a while to wrap my head around the comments.cheers guys

**edit2:** im sorry, i really dont know how to post the array here, the array looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buF6S.png)

- so far i was able to use foreach loop only in this way, which obviously just writes out the value at the beginning but 20 times. **how do i make it loop through all of the array items, and write all of them out?**

```
 foreach ($all_pics_clear as $value) {
            echo "{ type: 'quiz', title: '"
                .$all_pics_clear[0]
                ."', pic: '"
                .str_replace("pics-new/","",$all_pics[0])
                ."' },<br>";
        }
```

Comment: You're not getting to the foreach. I'm going to guess line 38 is `$all_pics_clear = str_replace(["pics/",".jpg",".png"],"",$all_pics);`, which won't work because glob returns an array, not a string, so str_replace will not work.

Comment: So you are trying to `echo json_encode($all_pics);` in your own complicated way?

Comment: Or perhaps there is more to it, but it's really really hard to debug something that you don't see (the array). Post the array here as an var_export so that we can help you.

Comment: What's the value of  `$all_pics`? We don't know what your content in the `pics/*.*` folder is.

Comment: Thank you so far. The fact that glob returns arrays was quite needed. Otherwise, aren´t all beginners doing things unnecessarily complicated? haha i dont know how to post the array as an var_export, so i at least added the image of the array, if it should be done differently, please tell me. The content in the pics folder are literally pictures (either png or jpg).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($all_pics as $filename) {
```

here `$all_pics` is the array, while `$filename` is the content of each item, which you want to use inside the loop.

You're referencing `$all_pics` and `$all_pics_clear` inside the loop. Both are arrays, that why you are getting that warning when trying to concatenate those with strings.

Also, if you want to get the key of an item inside the loop you may use `... as $key => $value` construct:

```php
foreach ($all_pics as $i => $filename) {
        echo "{ type: 'quiz', title: '"
            .$all_pics_clear[$i] // use $i-th item from $all_pics_clear array
            ."', pic: '"
            .str_replace("pics-new/","",$filename) // use $filename (which is the $i-th item from $all_pics)
            ."' },<br>";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had something to do with the $key => $value, but I really had no idea how to utilize it. Thank you for those explanations as well, I just wanted to understand properly the error I was getting and at the same time I wasn´t content with using for loop haha